# use QT with DLL compiled with -MT crash

Tags: crash, shared, qt5.7, mt

I compiled QT dynamic with -MT( modify config file )

my code is like this( my program is release mode with MT too ):

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )

{
    int ret = 0;

    if( 0 == ret )
    {
        QApplication a( argc, argv );
        {
            test01 w;
            w.show();
            ret = a.exec();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

test01 is very simple like this:

class test01 : public QMainWindow

{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    test01(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~test01();

private:
    Ui::test01Class ui;
};
```

everything is ok, but when leave main function, it crashed:

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

Anyone will help me?

Comment: The image is not added